# Huawei Site Kit - What is the alternative solution in HMS to get place name from lat-long and get address from lat-long

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am using geolocator flutter plugin  to get place name from latlong and get address from latlong , What is the alternative solution in HMS to get place name from latlong and get address from latlong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is an alternative API(Rest API) in Site Kit using which you can achieve Forward Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding, please refer below link which will guide you to achieve the feature:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/web-api-geocoding-0000001078097838

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using the flutter plugin, assuming the multiplatform native support is important for your app beyond Huawei mobile phones, the best matching solution in HMS would be to use the Reverse Geocoding REST Site Kit API to get place name and address from latlong in one RESTful webservice call. For detailed information about the API, please refer to the following website page [Site Kit-Reverse Geocoding (huawei.com)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/webapi-reverse-geo-0000001050161968-V5).

The API returns a collection of site objects and an example of the JSON object is provided as below. You can see the address is at top and name is near the bottom of the returned site object.

```
{
            "formatAddress": "Piazzale Dante, 41, 55049 Viareggio, Tuscany, Italy",
            "address": {
                "country": "Italy",
                "streetNumber": "41",
                "countryCode": "IT",
                "tertiaryAdminArea": "Viareggio",
                "postalCode": "55049",
                "locality": "Viareggio",
                "adminArea": "Tuscany",
                "subAdminArea": "Lucca",
                "thoroughfare": "Piazzale Dante"
            },
            "aoiFlag": false,
            "poi": {
                "hwPoiTypes": [
                    "NATIONAL_RAILWAY_STATION"
                ],
                "rating": 0.0,
                "icon": "https://lfcontentcenterdev.hwcloudtest.cn/pub_1/HuaweiMaps_camp_0_9/ec/v3/vut4tpV7SaOciBZ2xc1yMw/Railway.png",
                "internationalPhone": "",
                "poiTypes": [
                    "TRAIN_STATION"
                ]
            },
            "viewport": {
                "southwest": {
                    "lng": 10.25073768878106,
                    "lat": 43.87264496679441
                },
                "northeast": {
                    "lng": 10.25426631121894,
                    "lat": 43.875188633205596
                }
            },
            "name": "Viareggio",
            "siteId": "652973768919107712",
            "location": {
                "lng": 10.252502,
                "lat": 43.8739168
            }
        }
```